# Failed to generate signed apk on intellij

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I created an android game using libgdx library on Intellij, and when I try to generate the signed apk I get an error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':android:lintVitalRelease'.
> originalComplianceLevel
```

Before that error I had another one which was about the minimum sdk, it had to be 9 but the declared one was 8, but now is fixed.

also my game has ads, the only part of my game that I don't understand because I just copied the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
```

add this in your gradle file under android tag